# PHP Multiple Attachement Mail Delivery

Tags: php, sendmail, attachment

```
    $from = "test@localhost.com";
    $to = "test@localhost.com";
    $subject =$_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['body'];

    // include the from email in the headers
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary
    $time = md5(time());
    $boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$time}x";

    // headers used for send attachment with email
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
                "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
                " boundary=\"{$boundary}\"";

    // multipart boundary
    $message =  "--{$boundary}\n" . 
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

    // Fily Type Validation 
    $allowedExtensions = array("jpeg","jpg");

    // attach the attachments to the message
    $files = $_FILES['imgupload'];

    for($i=0; $i < count($files['name']); $i++)
        {
            if ($files['name'][$i] != '') 
            {
            $file_name = $files['name'][$i];
            $file_path = pathinfo($file_name);
            $file_ext = $file_path['extension'];
                if (in_array($file_ext, $allowedExtensions)) 
                {               
                $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
                $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmp_name)));
                $message .= 
                            "--{$boundary}\n" .
                            "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . 
                            " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
                            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . 
                            " filename=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
                            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $content . "\n\n";

                } else { $errormgs= 'alert("File Type is not accepted, please use an image.")'; $formerrors = 'true'; }
            } // else { $errormgs= 'alert("You Forgot to Attach the Photo")'; $formerrors = 'true'; }
        }

    // sending mail
    if (!$formerrors) 
    {
        $sendmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }  else 
    {
        print '<script type="text/javascript">';
        print $errormgs;
        print '</script>';  
    }
```

This is the script I have written which allows you to create as many input field in your form and deliver the attachment to the dedicated email without changing the PHP code for every additional attachment input field.

The only problem I have is an alert for the attachment fields. If there is no file selected I want the popup with the message demanding the image to be added. For some reason it doesn't work. If I add the else statement with the message the form keeps giving me that alert no matter if I add the Image or don't. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all for help and sorry for my language if I am expressing myself baddy.

Comment: You don't set $formerrors UNLESS an illegal file type was uploaded. You never handle the case where no uploads were done. As well, your code is highly verbose.. you should be using Swiftmailer or PHPMailer, both of which will reduce the whole attachment business to a single line of code per file.

Comment: Side note: You don't "compile" PHP scripts.

Comment: I need to handle the case were the upload is done, because its essential for the form. If there is no attachments submitted the form is pretty much useless.

Comment: Marc B 4 what do you mean by my code being highly verbose?